# Problem with transcription of short audios (yes, no ) with Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-speech-api

I'm having difficulties when trying to transcribe short user audio answers such as "yes", or "no".

I'm using dialogFlow detectIntent function, using audio as input, but same thing happens using Google Speech-To-Text API. I assume both use the same algorithms. Basically the problem is that there are a lot of cases where the response is empty

Audios clips are taken from a phone call (MULAW, 8KHz) and encoding and sample rate match what I'm sending in the request, because it works with almost all the audios.

We only have a problem with short responses. We hear the audio and the word (yes/no) is quite clear, but both dialogFlow and Google Speech-To-Text returns an empty response.

Did someone have the same problem? Is there any configuration that can be applied to solve or mitigate this problem?

Comment: We have similar issues with short answers like yes/no on dialogflow, did you get anywhere on this?

Comment: If you are working with english language, you can try adding yes and no to the phraseHints parameter. It improved the recognition. But for other languages (spanish in my case) it doesn't work.
Another thing that you can try, is to add some silence at the begining of your audio clip, if that's doable